# Multiple ImageButtons, each using 2 unique (from each other's) image for background, how do I write "selector" in XML?

Tags: java, android, selector

- I have 24 buttons
- They all have 2 states
- Each of the state of all 24 buttons (a.k.a 48 images) are different

How do I write all of the states in one selector in xml? Or do I need 24 xmls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is a problem best solved by making your own Button subclass and using that to declare items.

An oldie but a goodie post by Diane Hackborn : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/0xzI2bzY-20

Her answer iterated here:

> You could easily make your own custom subclass of button, though, that
>   had three attributes for the three different drawables and created a
>   state list drawable itself from them.  Then you could have everything
>   in your single layout file.